# Как написать приложения для работы с БД?

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Знания по Android у меня cчитайте что **0**... Мне дали задание:

> Напиши приложение, где можно регистрировать пользователей, после регистрации должно перейти на страницу где есть список зарегистрированных пользователей. Нажав на пользователя, должно перейти на страницу пользователя , где есть информация о нем (имя дата рождения, все что он указывал при регистрации). Вот и все)

1. Страница входа
2. Страница регистрации
3. Страница списка пользователей
4. Страница информации о пользователе

Подскажите пожалуйста что мне использовать в качестве технологий? И какую базу данных мне использовать SQLite или MySQL?

И где можно посмотреть годные туториалы по таким примерным заданиям? Я немного научился писать за пару дней простенькие программы, только вот этих знаний совсем мало для такого задания..

Comment: используй SQLite. А задание очень простое, и бд будет в одну таблицу.

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть на ютубе StartAndroid уроки. Там есть похожее задание.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Хорошо, буду использовать SQLite)

Comment: @НикитаРязанский Оо вот там много примочек) Спасибо большое за информацию) Как раз начну смотреть :))

Comment: @KryTer_NexT а так же рекомендую канал DevColibri, тоже есть что почерпнуть.

Comment: к сожалению, на ваш вопрос не существует объективного ответа. Такие вопросы, к сожалению, подлежат закрытию.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу sql почитай про `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Не запаривайся для этого задания с `ListView`, прочти про `View.inflate()` и про `.addView()` для `LinearLayout`. Для экранов используй fragment, а также singletone. Если не будут докапываться, то прокатит и за 3 дня успеешь.

Если хочешь оставь координаты, помогу советами, чтобы на глупые ошибки много времени не тратил. Удачи

Comment: Окей, спасибо большое за советы)) уже не 3 а 2 дня осталось :( Активити построил, все что надо сделал, вот главная проблема это база данных... Ща сижу смотрю туториалы по SQLitе...